# How important is the TYPE of FIELD when building a database schema?

Tags: mysql

When selecting a field type there are lots of options that are based on what data will be stored but how important is it that I select a specific type? If I am using a single character integer or boolean whats the harm in making the type LONGTEXT?

Does it take up more data to store it that way?

Thanks.

Comment: Space, Speed, Usability (functions you can use), all that depends on the data types you use

Comment: So if I make a field type LONGTEXT it takes up more space than if I make it INT regardless of what is stored in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what type of data you are going to use, then use that type. A `bit` is a  `boolean` and takes a single bit of data apposed to an `integer` which takes 2 bytes. So using the proper data types is important in not using large quantities of memory which would lead to slow queries.

`LONGTEXT` size in bytes is equal to the (number of characters + 1)